# Copy data from another Excel file with VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to open a workbook and copy from the opened workbooks sheet to my worbook sheet like that:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim openedFile As String
    Dim sourcebook As Workbook
    openedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm") 'Source book opening

    Set sourcebook = Workbooks.Open(openedFile)

    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    sourcebook.Worksheets("source_sheet").Range("A1:L100").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dest_sgheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call sourcebook.Close(False)
End Sub
```

I got this error message after I runing this code:

> Run-time error '1004": PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

It's occour at this line:

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dest_sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 0):

try activating the workbook first ("This workbook") and then activating the sheet where you'd like to paste the data. The error tends to occur because either the range is not visible nor in existence.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work .
change this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dest_sgheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

with this one:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dest_sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

**EDIT**
Based on OP comments on 25-05-2016 I have re-run the program as per OP code after correcting minor typo error in sheet spelling. Program runs successfully without any problem. I am not getting Run time error 1004. Screenshot shows that data is getting copied properly.

[image: screenshot showing input and output]

Comment: This too line is almost identical, except of the sheet names, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Twi I have tested your code on sample data and found it perfectly working. If you have doubts please let me know.

Comment: @Twi We put efforts to check code of our peers with a view to help them. The basic issue is whether this program code worked out by you is faulty which leads to generation of Run Time error 1004. We put efforts in compiling sample data and analyse your code to see its working. Normally such minor things are informed through comments. In this case there was already an answer which appeared not to fully address your problem clearly and considering that I have spent my precious time in analysing your problem, it was inadvertantly put as an answer. I apologize if it has hurt your feelings.